# Scrapy find element by part of id and split attribute value

Tags: scrapy, css-selectors

I'm new to Scrapy and am trying to create a CSS selector that finds an element by part of the id, and split its `value` attribute to get the nth item. So far I have been working with simple selectors, like these:

```
item['url'] = response.url # get url        
item['address'] = response.css('span.address::text').get().strip() # get address
```

However, now I want to select this element (all that have id start with `mger`) and split the value in its `value` attribute:

`<input type="hidden" id="mger21110564343" name="mger21110564343" value="21110564343~1~50.37396877,5.90523487~2222GH">`

I've been studying this page: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#id1 and Google but am still not sure how to do it.

Normally with regular CSS selectors I would use `[id^=mger]`.

Pseudocode of what I want, to get value `21110564343` from `value` attribute:

```
response.css("[id^=mger]").attr('value').get().split("~")(0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your css should work, but the selector should look like this:

```
selector.css('[id^=mger]::attr(value)').get()
```

with scrapy you can also use `xpath` (in fact, css selectors get translated to xpath), so you can also use:

```
response.xpath('//*[starts-with(@id, "mger")]/@value').get()
```

If you are not getting information, maybe it means that the elements don't actually exist in the response body, you'll have to confirm that first